# Bit type in MySQL and PHP support failure

Tags: php, mysql

I am keeping type of user account in `bit(16)` field in MySQL. All queries for selected user types work fine: `SELECT * FROM users WHERE type & 8` - gives good results.

I am getting my row to `$_SESSION`, but after that `$_SESSION['userdata']['type'] & 8` gives `0`. Why is that?

`var_dump($_SESSION['userdata'])` gives `... ["type"]=> string(2) "" ...` so it seems to be fine.

Any idea why doesn't it work and how to fix or at least debug it?

Encoding of site is `UTF8`, encoding of php file is `UTF8`, encoding of database is `UTF8`, encoding of database connection is `UTF8`.

`bindec()` PHP function doesn't help. It returns 0.

Comment: seems like you are ANDing string of bytes with numbers.

Comment: Row data que gets the field as string, shouldn't it be integer to apply bitwise and?

Comment: So it was a bad idea to keep it as BIT() in database? Or what should I do now?

Comment: `bindec()` doesnt help, it returns 0. And it's not 0!

Comment: @FlashThunder I'd try `ord()` or something similar on the result characters from db, you want to convert the pure byte values into integer before ANDing. You need to convert each character separately and then multiply the first by 256. There might as well be better function for it.

Comment: You should cast your `$_SESSION['userdata']['type']` to integer before using bitwise and (`&`) operation.

Comment: I think ill change it to INT in database...

Comment: @FlashThunder that's weird, seems like `bindec` would be the way to go.

Comment: @enrey yes, it is weird. thats why I'll better simply change database structure, as changing it to int should slow down much, I hope.

Comment: Wouldn’t it make more sense to maybe use an ENUM or SET instead …?

Comment: @CBroe with SET you have to define allowed values in table structure. This is not the option, as those values may vary and I won't change whole database to add another user role.

Comment: Altering table to change bit(16) to int worked fine.

Comment: @enrey was right about using `bindec()` instead of integer casting, `BIT` fields are stored as binary data internally. Since you're using MySQL, you might want to use `TINYINT` instead, which allow values fron range -128 to 127 or 0 to 255 when unsigned. :)

Comment: TINYINT doesn't allow me to make bitwise operations, because it will have only 8 bits, that is not enough storage data. of course I could simply define 1 = something, 2 = something else, 3 = something else else ... but I don't want to, because I need to be able to set more than one user type per user. And with bitwise operations it is as simple as `$type = UT_USER | UT_MODERATOR;` with predefined constants of course. Anybody knows if bitwise operations on `int` field type would be much slower than on `bit`?

Comment: My guess is it should be exactly the same, since the data is the same, the type in this case just says in which way would you like to read your data. That's just a guess. But even if it's wrong guess, this isn't something to worry about, bit arithmetic is freakishly fast, plus you probably aren't gonna need millions of those AND or OR operations on your users, or are you?

Answer (score 0):

As there is no answer to accept, I will answer myself, because this may be something useful for others.

When using `bit` field type in MySQL, PHP casts it to string. As, by default PHP doesn't threat strings as binary numbers, it simply converts it to 0 when trying to do some bitwise operation. Not sure why, but `bindec()` function doesn't seem to be working properly, so there are two options:

1. Cast a `bit` field to integer in MySQL query, by simply adding `+0` to it, like this: `SELECT bit_field+0 FROM table`
2. Change a field to `unsigned int`. It will be usable same way as `bit`, but will return right value without any convertion.

As for efficiency - as far as I read, `int`s are kept in the same form as `bit`s and bitwise operations are made exactly the same way, so it should be comparable.

**Credits** to everyone who commented the question.